# What's Wrong In This Python Program

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
num1=int(input("Enter Number of Elements For first list :"))
list1=[]
for i in range(num1):
    ele=[input("Enter element of list 1 :")]
    list1.append(ele)


new_list = [(i,pow(i,2)) for i in list1]

print(list1)

print(new_list)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/naray/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/touple6.py", line 8, in <module>
    new_list = [(i,pow(i,2)) for i in list1]
  File "C:/Users/naray/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/touple6.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    new_list = [(i,pow(i,2)) for i in list1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: What prompted you to ask a question about it? What do you already know is wrong with it?

Comment: `ele=[input("Enter element of list 1 :")]` makes `ele` a list with one item in, so `list1` is a list of lists. Therefore each `i` you access in `list1` is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

- You cannot use `pow()` on list, `pow` is always called on numbers

Solution:

- Instead of appending a list to `list1`, just convert the input to `int` and append the number `ele`.

This code should work fine

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter Number of Elements For first list :"))
list1 = []
for i in range(num1):
    ele = int(input("Enter element of list 1 :"))
    list1.append(ele)

new_list = [(i, pow(i, 2)) for i in list1]

print(list1)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```py
Enter Number of Elements For first list :2
Enter element of list 1 :10
Enter element of list 1 :20
[10, 20]
[(10, 100), (20, 400)]
```

Comment: No need to import any kinda module

Comment: i hope it does work on you machine